# Convergence of polynomials pointwise implies convergence uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

Let $P_n$ be a sequence of real polynomials of degree $\le 10$. Suppose $P_n(x)$ converges pointwise to 0 as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $x \in [0,1]$. Prove that $P_n$ converges uniformly to 0.

Now the hint said to consider $P_{10}$ as a vector space and consider the open ball of radius $R$ around $0 \in P_{10}$. For some basis, define a mapping $$f: P_{10} \to \mathbb{R}$$ by 
$$f: \mathbb{R}^{11} \ni v \to \sup_{[0,1]}\, \Bigl|\sum_{k=0}^{10} v_kx^k\Bigr|$$  where $v$ is the co-ordinate representation of $p \in P_{10}$ according to some basis. Note $f \in \mathscr{C}$, i.e. is continuous. Now, since $B_R (0) \subset P_{10}$, if we can show that $M =\max{f(B_R (0))} \to 0$ as $R \to 0$, we have uniform convergence.

Could someone help explain why $M \to 0$ implies uniform convergence? Moreover, how to show that this is true.

I've seen linear algebra methods, but I want to see an analysis method.

Comment: Once you've written $\sum_{k=0}^{10}\nu_kx^k$ *some* basis becomes *the* basis $x^k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not used point-wise convergence in your construction. You need  to prove (besides to what you've mentioned) that

> $$
> p_n(x)\to 0,\ \forall x\in[0,1]\quad\Rightarrow\quad \mathbb{R}^{11}\ni\nu_n\to 0.
> $$

Then the rest is obvious 
$$
\|\nu_n\|\to 0\quad\Rightarrow\quad\nu_n\in B_{R_n}(0),\ R_n\to 0\quad\Rightarrow\quad \|p_n\|_\infty=f(\nu_n)\le M_n\to 0.
$$

P.S. To prove that $M\to 0$ consider the estimate
$$
\left|\sum_{k=0}^{10}\nu_k x^k\right|\le \sum_{k=0}^{10}|\nu_k||x^k|\le 
\sum_{k=0}^{10}|\nu_k|\|x^k\|_\infty\le \sum_{k=0}^{10}|\nu_k|.
$$

Comment: This estimate being so because our domain is $[0,1]$, yes?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter Right, otherwise $|x^k|\le \|x^k\|_\infty\le C_k<+\infty$

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something. Is $R \to 0$ point-wise convergence? Where does it get its metric? Are we not taking the metric induced by the sup metric on $C([0,1[)$? I suppose I'm a bit confused in regards to how to include point-wise convergence.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter You *need to prove* that pointwise convergence implies $\nu_n\to 0$, i.e. $R_n=\|\nu_n\|\to 0$. A possible way: choose $11$ distinct points $x_m\in[0,1]$ and build a matrix $A$ so that $A\nu_n=[p_n(x_0)...p_n(x_{10})]^T\to 0$. What can you say about $\nu_n$?